# Potential bottleneck Azure Databricks Cluster

Tags: azure, apache-spark, bigdata, cluster-computing, databricks

I am facing an issue with dabricks cluster. When saving a 20 billon rows dataset, it is taking days. But when I analyse cpu performance, it comes up that the following usage:

-46.8% iddle
-9.2% user
-43.4% wait
-0.7 system.

The cluster is a multi node with 4 workers and photon aceleration technology. Memory performance has 100gb free from a total of 700gb.

What does "wait" means? Is there something i can do to speed up the process? What else can i analyze to improve times?

Best regards

Comment: Where are you saving the data frame to?

Comment: blob storage, as a delta table